# Select element closest to top of a window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fixed list of page sections on the side, as page gets scrolled the link to section you're on gets highlighted. At least that's what I've been trying to achieve.

The best I came up with:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
$allSections = $('section[id^="section"]');
$allSections.each(function(){
  if ( ($(this).offset().top - window.pageYOffset) > 0 && 
       ($(this).offset().top - window.pageYOffset) < $(window).height()/2 ){  
  $("a[href$=" + (this).id + "]").addClass('highlight');
  } else {
    $("a[href$=" + (this).id + "]").removeClass('highlight');
  }
});
});
```

The above selects sections whose top edge is below top and above half of the window. Unfortunately with long sections there are scrolls where none get selected and with short sections there are scrolls where it selects more that 1 as my fiddle presents. https://jsfiddle.net/aetkgpxc/50/

How to select element(from group of elements) whose top edge is nearest to top of the window?

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

I have updated your code and it works fine here.

### JS

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $allSections = $('section[id^="section"]');
    $allSections.each(function(){
      if ( ($(this).offset().top - window.pageYOffset) > 0 && 
           ($(this).offset().top - window.pageYOffset) < $(window).height()/2 ){  
      $("a").removeClass('highlight');     
      $("a[href$=" + (this).id + "]").addClass('highlight');
      } 
    });
  });
```

### Here is a jsfiddle

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/aetkgpxc/57/)

### Update

https://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/aetkgpxc/62/

### JS

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $allSections = $('section[id^="section"]');
    $allSections.each(function(){
      if ( ($(this).offset().top - window.pageYOffset) <= 0 && 
           ($(this).offset().top - window.pageYOffset) < $(window).height()/2 ){  
      $("a").removeClass('highlight');     
      $("a[href$=" + (this).id + "]").addClass('highlight');
      } else {
        $("a[href$=" + (this).id + "]").removeClass('highlight');
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Selecting more than 1 problem is no longer there - thanks, but when top of one section is above window's top and next section's top is not yet in window -  none gets selected.